# Removed Listview count and builder properties on Flutter 2.0.4 version

Tags: flutter, dart

I have updated my flutter project from v1.22.6 to v2.0.4. I got lots of errors. I tried to fix the dart problem using the dart fix command to but I could not figure it out.
I have used listview. builder for list view but the item count and **builder** property are not available on updated flutter version 2.0.4

//Code Snippet is:-

[image]

//Flutter Doctor Snippet:-

[image]

Comment: it defines : class ListView extends BoxScrollView {}

Comment: What is the error you get for itemCount?

Comment: You can always do the following: run "flutter clean", then "flutter pub get", then restart the Dart Analysis server (or the IDE)

Comment: @all for my whole project it gives the same error which is highlighted in red color.

Comment: ListView.builder({Key key, Axis scrollDirection = Axis.vertical, bool reverse = false, ScrollController controller, bool primary, ScrollPhysics physics, bool shrinkWrap = false, EdgeInsetsGeometry padding, double itemExtent, dynamic IndexedWidgetBuilder})

Comment: @pskink yes I have seen too. count and builder property is available there.

Comment: I Have created new file the name is : - BreakdownScreen

Comment: scroll_view.dart file

Comment: I think this is a problem in my project. Because I have just created the demo project and it works.

Comment: yes, 1154 it is

Comment: Yes it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run flutter clean.
- Completely close your editor and open it again.
- Wait for the analyzer to finish analyzing your project, the errors should be gone.
- It happens sometimes when upgrading, or cloning new projects, certain errors such as `color is not defined` have popped up a few times, this only happened in VScode for me, but all goes away.

This image is from Flutter 2.0.4.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have deleted the project. Clone new one did the same steps. It works.

Comment: You're most welcome, happy it helped! Kindly consider marking it as a helpful answer if it solved your issue, thanks!